# DynamoDB Transactions: How to use the result of a GetItem in the next PutItem

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible in DynamoDB Transactions to:

1. Update an item in table A (increment the value of an item to be specific to my scenario)
2. Use the updated value of the attribute in a PutItem to another table B.

The transaction should preserve atomicity - so they should either succeed or fail as a unit.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Basically you want it as one call to a DynamoDB API?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Hcaertnit Not as a single API call necessarily, but as a single transactional unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [DynamoDB Transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html).

From the linked docs:

> Amazon DynamoDB transactions simplify the developer experience of making coordinated, all-or-nothing changes to multiple items both within and across tables. Transactions provide atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability (ACID) in DynamoDB, helping you to maintain data correctness in your applications.

DynamoDB transactions give you an all-or-nothing operation that can span across tables.  If a single operation in the transaction fails, the entire transaction fails and the operations are not applied to the Databse.  This is in contrast to batch operations, which can succeed or fail independently.

Comment: True, but the OP knows this and is specifically asking about a specific set of actions using Transactions.